# how to read public struct from contract ABI using ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, dapps

The contract has a struct which is used in an mapping. The blockchain explorers "code read" section allows to receive the result by providing a wallet address.

Solidity Code

```
struct Share {
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 totalExcluded;
    uint256 totalRealised;
}
mapping (address => Share) public shares;
```

I'm trying to receive the struct for one wallet like below

```
 var contract = new ethers.Contract(contractCA, abi, provider)
 walletSharesRealized = await contract.shares(account);
```

The error output I receive is as below

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="shares", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.4.0)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the explanation here, https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/formats/#abi-formats--human-readable-abi

You can write a human readable abi code. The struct is translated into a tuple.

ABI

```
function shares(address addr) public view returns (tuple(uint amount, uint totalExcluded, uint totalRealised))
```